# this.xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName is not a function

Tags: javascript, xml, local-storage, httprequest

Hi im trying to get the score elements from an xmlto then upload to the local storage i have the xml upload as you can see in this image
[xmluploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1P7nT.png) but when i try to get the elements of Score it appears this error this.xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName is not a function ,i would appreciate the help.

```
class XML_Database {
constructor () {
     this.xmlDoc = null;
}

loadXMLfile(path, callback){

    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET",path,true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
    request.onreadystatechange= function(){
        if(request.readyState=== XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status==200){
            callback(request.responseXML);
        }
    };
    request.send()



}
SearchXML (query, num_scores) {
    let Scores = [];
    let x = this.xmlDoc.getElementsByClassName(query);
    if (num_scores> x.length) {
        num_scores= x.length;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < num_scores; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < x[i].childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (x[i].childNodes[j].nodeName == "Value") {
                Scores.push(x[i].childNodes[j].textContent);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return Scores;
}

setXMLDoc(xmlDoc){
    this.xmlDoc = xmlDoc;
}
```

and this is when i call the methods

```
 set_xml(){
    const self = this;
    let new_XML_file = "/xml/Scores_Database.xml";
    this.XML_db.setXMLDoc(new_XML_file);
    this.XML_db.loadXMLfile(new_XML_file,function(xml){
        console.log(xml);
        self.XML_db.SearchXML("Score", 5) ;
    });
    }
```

Comment: `new_XML_file` is a string. `.setXMLDoc` stores this string in `this.xmlDoc`. And a string has no `.getElementsByClassName()` method.

Comment: Your code calls `setXMLDoc()` with a string, not an XML document reference.